# Warning | 3156 | Invalid JSON value for CAST to INTEGER from column json_search at row 1 |

Tags: mysql, json

My Sample JSON

```
{"feeds": [{"trait": "Bankrupt", "rating": "medium", "observation": "mortgage problems", "riskscaling": "4"}, {"trait": "Incompetency", "rating": "high", "observation": "work problems", "riskscaling": "5"}, {"trait": "Mental Stress", "rating": "low", "observation": "personal problems", "riskscaling": "3"}], "ad_uidNumber": "2021041913", "ad_employeeID": "tom.banks"}
```

I am getting error as

> Warning | 3156 | Invalid JSON value for CAST to INTEGER from column json_search at row 1 |

when I hit qry as

```
select distinct globalusers.id 
from globalusers 
where (JSON_SEARCH(dynamic_attributes->>'$.feeds[*].trait','all', 'Bankrupt'));
```

Anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select distinct id 
from globalusers
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(dynamic_attributes, 'all', 'Bankrupt', NULL, '$.feeds[*].trait') IS NOT NULL
```

or

```sql
select distinct globalusers.id 
from globalusers 
where JSON_SEARCH(dynamic_attributes->>'$.feeds[*].trait','all', 'Bankrupt') IS NOT NULL
```

or (array unquoting makes no sense)

```sql
select distinct globalusers.id 
from globalusers 
where JSON_SEARCH(dynamic_attributes->'$.feeds[*].trait','all', 'Bankrupt') IS NOT NULL
```

---

`JSON_SEARCH` returns either found path(s) or NULL.

> Warning | 3156 | Invalid JSON value for CAST to INTEGER from column json_search at row 1 |

is produced because found path which starts not from a digit cannot be converted to BOOLEAN correctly.